# Issue in new Desktop 21.04

Tags: upgrade, desktop-environments, .desktop

I have an issue with Ubuntu 21.04. After upgrading I noticed all my files in the desktop went to a folder named Desktop in Documents. How can I transfer them back to the desktop screen? When I select *Move to* or *Copy* I can't make them go in the desktop. It's like the Desktop is restricted to not be able to add files too.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to install `gnome-tweak-tool` and then enable the "Desktop icons ng" extension. Here's how you can do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install Gnome Tweaks:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
3. Open Gnome Tweaks:
   [image: Gnome tweaks]
4. In the "Extensions" tab, ensure the top toggle is enabled as well as "Desktop icons ng":
   [image: Gnome Tweaks - Extensions]
5. Copy/Paste/Move files to the desktop to your heart's content

> **Note:** One issue that I see with this extension is that you cannot delete files from the desktop with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. Instead you will need to right-click, then choose "Move to trash"

Comment: thank you very much. it worked well & files back to their original places.

Comment: Please consider "accepting" the answer if it helped you: click the checkmark next to the question

Comment: @matigo better now recommend to use the dedicated 'extensions' tool, i.e. `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`: more reliable for system extensions, and moreover, the management of gnome shell extensions will be removed from Tweaks anyway.

Comment: @vanadium if `Tweaks` was installed from the USC, is it still preferable to install `gnome-shell=extension-prefs`?

Comment: At some point (in 19.10) I found I could not reliably enable/disable the system Desktop Icons extension with Tweaks, but there was no problem with Extensions.